# Internal error C:\Program Files\OpenModelica1.21.0-64bit\bin\OMEdit.exe: [unknown function name] failed

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I want to simulate an old model and it dosen't work. This is the warning I get but I don't understand it:

```
Internal error C:\Program Files\OpenModelica1.21.0-64bit\bin\OMEdit.exe: [unknown function name] failed
```

Comment: Can you give more info what you did to encounter the error message? What program did you start, what steps did you do? Where is this error message coming from?
In short: How to reproduce the error

Comment: If i remeber correctly this usually happens when building the C code from the model (when calling the Susan templates). I guess you could try to use the old frontend and see if that works but is better to just make a bug report with more information:https://github.com/OpenModelica/OpenModelica/issues/new/choose

Comment: Hi! Thank you AnHeuermann and Adrian. I fixed the problem. I had the OpenModelica program file hidden by accident. If it happens again I can use the frontend. Thank you for taking your time to answer muy question!